# Getting status: code on ajax response in a .js.erb file on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ajax, respond-to

I've just started to play with Rails applications and I'm trying to use Ajax on a form, but I don't know how to catch the status code inside a js.erb file. I'm following this tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

On my Users controller I have a code for my update method:

```
respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
            format.js {}
            format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user}
        else 
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.js {}
            format.json { render json: @user, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            logger.debug @user.response_errors
        end         
    end
```

I've created a update.js.erb file inside my views/users/ folder and is very easy to debug the @user var, but I don't know how to get the status code setted on my method.

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I'm new with rails and I'm trying to follow all the frameworks concepts to the letter and I don't know the best pratices to create responses to Ajax requests.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
#on my update.js.erb
if( status == 'created' ) {
   alert( 'Ok, created' )
} else {
   alert( 'Something wrong happened' )
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: Check Validity Inside `update.js.erb`

This is the option that I recommend in most cases.

`update.js.erb` is an ERB template whose result is a JavaScript code to evaluate on the client. In this case, you can make it look like:

```
<% if @user.valid? %>
  alert('Ok, created');
<% else %>
  alert('Something wrong happened');
<% end %>
```

The decision which alert to displays happens server-side. The client receives either:

```
alert('Ok, create');
```

or

```
alert('Something wrong happened');
```

depending on the status of `@user`.

## Option 2: Two separate `js.erb` files

You can split your `update.js.erb` into two files. `update.js.erb` should contain the happy path code:

```
alert('Ok, create');
```

`update-error.js.erb` should contain some error handling:

```
alert('Something wrong happened');
```

Then you decide which one to display in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    # ...
    format.js {}
    # ...
  else 
    # ...
    format.js { render 'update-error' }
    # ...
  end         
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Greg, the first option works very well and suits my needs.
My only doubt still with that status setted on my code:

`format.json { render json: @user, status: :unprocessable_entity }`

There's a reason to set that?

Comment: Yes, I think that responding with 200 would be incorrect and the status code you chose seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do:

> format.js {render json: {@user,  status: :created, location: @user}}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it thrown a syntax error:

/.../app/controllers/users_controller.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...format.js {render json: {@user, status: :unprocessable_entit... ... ^